# How send javasript with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to return javascript with an Express server, not html document,

I tried

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.type('.js');
  res.send("var danny = new Human();");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening at http://localhost:5000');
});
```

but I just get `<pre>var danny = new Human();</pre>` as html response :/

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What do you want the browser to do with the script ? execute ?

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the result. You are sending JS to the browser. The browser just isn't doing what you expect with it.

If you type the URL of some JS into the address bar of the browser, then it will generate an HTML document to display that script's source code.

Browsers will only execute JS if it is loaded with a `<script>` element in an HTML document (or via a browser extension).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
You can use `res.sendFile(__dirname + "path/to/file.js")`